# After first tap UI doesn't respond to anything

Tags: android, ios, react-native, detox

I'm using Detox to test. It was working fine for react-native 0.57.
But, when I upgrade the project to react-native 0.60.4 it stopped working, the simulator does not respond to anything after the first interaction on the screen, when I build the app for debugging or release it works fine, but for the detox test you cannot have interaction with the app, it simply does not respond to anything.

This behaviour happens both iOS and Android.